# Define size for .gif created by gganimate - change dimension / resolution

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I'm using `gganimate` to create some .gif files that I want to insert into my reports. I'm able to save the files and view them fine, however, I find that the displayed size is small: 480x480. Is there a way to adjust that - perhaps along the lines of `height` and `width` arguments in `ggsave()`?

I can zoom in but that impacts the quality poorly and makes it rather unreadable for my use case.

Here's some sample code:

```
gplot <- 
  ggplot(gapminder, 
         aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, colour = continent, 
             size = pop, 
             frame = year)) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.6) + 
    scale_x_log10()

gganimate(gplot, "test.gif")
```

Below is the output for this code.

[image: test.gif]

Comment: I think you want `ani.options(ani.width=800, ani.height=400)` or set those to whatever you want.

Comment: @Tjebo thanks for bringing this up, I'll take a look and change the accepted answer if another option works better.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There can be issues with using the `magick` package.

I think a better solution is use the `animate()` function in `gganimate` to create an object which is then passed to the `anim_save()` function. No need to use another package.

```
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)

my.animation <- 
  ggplot(
  gapminder,
  aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, colour = continent, size = pop)
 ) +
geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
scale_x_log10() +
transition_time(year)

# animate in a two step process:
animate(my.animation, height = 800, width =800)
anim_save("Gapminder_example.gif")
```

Comment: using this approach, is there any approach to control resolution / dpi?

Comment: @radek yes. See my answer

Answer (score 26):

Although [Thomas suggests](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate/issues/96) to have a look at `animate`, the documentation is unfortunately not very clear in this regard.

`?animate` shows that device arguments can be specified via the `...` argument. You can find available arguments at [`?grDevices::png`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.4.1/topics/png) or [`?grDevices::svg`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grDevices/versions/3.4.1/topics/cairo).

You can directly control the resolution by specifying the `res` argument. And one can also use *different units*. I personally like to control my figure dimensions in inch and control the resolution based on that.
The advantage is to me, that there will be much less surprises with font sizes and of course the quality of the figure will be better.

Based on the example [provided by user Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52249774/7941188).

```
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)

my.animation <-
  ggplot(gapminder, aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, colour = continent, size = pop)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  transition_time(year) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 8)

animate(my.animation, height = 2,
  width = 3, units = "in", res = 150)

anim_save("gapminder_example.gif")
```

<sub>dimensions of 450x300px, as expected.</sub>
[image]

Comment: update, a pull request for updating the documentation was accepted, so this should now be available at least on the development version of gganimate

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: Your answer says "res=150" in `animate`. The docs for  `animate` have no description of "res", see https://gganimate.com/reference/animate.html. Can you link a reference that describes res?

Comment: @dfrankow this is all explained in my answer already... see _?animate shows that device arguments can be specified via the ... parameter. You can find available arguments at ?grDevices::png or ?grDevices::svg._ a better name for ... might be argument. I will change that.

Comment: I see, thank you! I did not understand that `res` was an argument to devices (i.e., linking to the preceding paragraph). Indeed when I look at `?grDevices::png`, it describes `res` precisely.

Answer (score 10):

Using the new API of [`gganimate`](https://github.com/thomasp85/gganimate) package, it is

```
library(gganimate)
library(gapminder)

gplot <- 
  ggplot(
    gapminder,
    aes(x = gdpPercap, y = lifeExp, colour = continent, size = pop)
  ) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.6) +
    scale_x_log10() +
    transition_time(year)

magick::image_write(
  animate(gplot, width = 1000, height = 1000), 
  "test.gif"
)
```

Comment: When I run this code I get this error


Error: The 'image' argument is not a magick image object.

Comment: Now, you can use `anim_save` like

`anim_save("test.gif", gplot, width = 1000, height = 1000)`

Answer (score 3):

You can either tune the general settings:

```
animation::ani.options(ani.width= 1000, ani.height=1000, ani.res = 1000)
```

or change the settings of each single command:

```
gganimate(gplot, ani.width= 1000, ani.height=1000, "test.gif")
```

Comment: ani.width & ani.height are now depreciated, see answer below