Save .gif with gganimate respecting the original ggplot
I have the following code which so far, works fine. The problem is when I try to save the animated gif. All of my tries end up losing quality of image, the text annotations get misplaced and the ratio of height and weight are not respected. How can I save the gif properly?
I've done this in the past but I don't know if the text annotations are making it more difficult or so.
pacman::p_load(gganimate, tidyverse, here)

# Setting consistent dimensions for both static and animated outputs
plot_width <- 12
plot_height <- 7
dpi_setting <- 300

# Motherhood Penalties | Uruguay

uruguay <- read_csv("name,confHigh,confLow,estimate,gender,t_es
                 Uruguay,0.0236,-7e-4,0.0114,male,-5
                 Uruguay,0.0276,-0.0589,-0.0157,female,-5
                 Uruguay,0.0087,-0.0157,-0.0035,male,-4
                 Uruguay,0.03,-0.048,-0.009,female,-4
                 Uruguay,0.0257,0.0028,0.0142,male,-3
                 Uruguay,0.0287,-0.0433,-0.0073,female,-3
                 Uruguay,0,0,0,male,-2
                 Uruguay,0,0,0,female,-2
                 Uruguay,0.0113,-0.0115,-1e-4,male,-1
                 Uruguay,0.0042,-0.0602,-0.028,female,-1
                 Uruguay,0.022,1e-4,0.011,male,0
                 Uruguay,-0.2773,-0.3384,-0.3079,female,0
                 Uruguay,0.0281,0.0064,0.0173,male,1
                 Uruguay,-0.2816,-0.3413,-0.3115,female,1
                 Uruguay,0.0188,-0.003,0.0079,male,2
                 Uruguay,-0.3002,-0.3575,-0.3288,female,2
                 Uruguay,0.0188,-0.0029,0.0079,male,3
                 Uruguay,-0.3197,-0.3748,-0.3472,female,3
                 Uruguay,0.0266,0.0052,0.0159,male,4
                 Uruguay,-0.3283,-0.3821,-0.3552,female,4
                 Uruguay,0.0192,-0.0027,0.0082,male,5
                 Uruguay,-0.3554,-0.4083,-0.3818,female,5
                 Uruguay,0.019,-0.0029,0.008,male,6
                 Uruguay,-0.3527,-0.4048,-0.3787,female,6
                 Uruguay,0.0195,-0.0025,0.0085,male,7
                 Uruguay,-0.3695,-0.421,-0.3953,female,7
                 Uruguay,0.0137,-0.0089,0.0024,male,8
                 Uruguay,-0.3565,-0.407,-0.3818,female,8
                 Uruguay,0.0163,-0.0062,0.0051,male,9
                 Uruguay,-0.3636,-0.4137,-0.3887,female,9
                 Uruguay,0.0118,-0.0112,3e-4,male,10
                 Uruguay,-0.3577,-0.4076,-0.3826,female,10")

(p <- uruguay |>
  mutate(pause = if_else(t_es == 0, 2, 1)) |> # set pause for 10 at zero
  uncount(pause) |> # repeat pause rows
  mutate(reveal = row_number(), .by = c(name, gender)) |> # set the reveal sequence
  ggplot(aes(t_es, estimate, group = gender, color = gender)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = -.5, linetype = "solid", color = "black", linewidth = .2) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "solid", color = "black") +
  geom_line(linewidth = 1.5) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#D90D0D", "#6A6654")) +
  theme_minimal(base_family = "Verdana",
                base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "",
       color = "",
       title = "Cambio en el empleo después de tener el primer hijo/a, %",
       subtitle = "Respecto a dos años antes del nacimiento",
       caption = "Fuente: elaboración propia en base a The Child Penalty Atlas, por H. Kleven et al., 2023.\nPaula Pereda Suárez | @paubgood") +
  geom_text(aes(x = -4, y = 0.0100, label = "Varones"), fontface = "bold", color = "#6A6654", vjust = -.5, family = "Verdana") +
  geom_text(aes(x = -4, y = -.03, label = "Mujeres"), fontface = "bold", color = "#D90D0D", vjust = -.5, family = "Verdana") +
  geom_text(aes(x = -.5, y = -.31, label = "-31%"), fontface = "bold", color = "#D90D0D", vjust = -.5, family = "Verdana") +
  geom_text(aes(x = 10, y = -.38, label = "-39%"), fontface = "bold", color = "#D90D0D", vjust = -.5, family = "Verdana") +
  annotate("text", x = -4, y = -.39,  label = "5 años antes", fontface = "bold", color = "black",   vjust = -.5) +
  annotate("text", x = 3.5, y = -.39,  label = "10 años después", fontface = "bold", color = "black",   vjust = -.5) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Verdana"),
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        axis.text = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        plot.background  = element_rect(fill  = "#F5F4EE",
                                        color = "#F5F4EE")))

# Save static plot
ggsave("uruguay.png", dpi = dpi_setting, width = plot_width, height = plot_height)

# Create and save the animated plot
anim <- p +
  transition_reveal(along = t_es) +
  enter_fade() + 
  exit_fade() +
  ease_aes('linear') +
  shadow_mark()

# Calculate the dimensions for the GIF that maintain the same aspect ratio and improve the resolution
gif_width <- 960  # Twice the pixel width for better detail
gif_height <- 560  # Calculated to maintain the aspect ratio

anim_save("motherhood_penalties_uy.gif", animation = anim, end_pause = 10, nframes = 150, fps = 25, width = gif_width, height = gif_height)



You have specific resolution settings for ggsave but for gganimate you are using other settings. I'd suggest using the same settings. See this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058567/define-size-for-gif-created-by-gganimate-change-dimension-resolution

This blog post is helpful for understanding ggplot2 resolution and how it changes the plot appearance: https://www.christophenicault.com/post/understand_size_dimension_ggplot2/
